# My MAMP localhost only runs one project on my code editor Sublime Text

Tags: html, css, sublimetext3, mamp

[image: htdocs_screenshot]
Hello,

I run Windows 10 and my Document Root for MAMP is C:\MAMP\htdocs. I use Sublime Text 3 to learn code,
The first html file I created is "index.html" 
The first css file I created is "main.css" 
The project I saved them under is titled "My First Project."

The html, css, and project files are all saved within htdocs. When I open up Sublime Text to edit "My First Project", the edits show up on my localhost. But when I close "My First Project" and open a new project titled "My Second Project"  and edit another html file titled "new_project" the edits do not show up on my localhost. Instead the same edits from "My First Project" do not disappear from my localhost. Am I not using Sublime Text correctly? How can I not have my previous project showing up on localhost when I refresh the screen and my code editor is on an entirely new html file?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not very clear, but if you're asking what I think you're asking, you're completely misunderstanding how projects work. A Sublime [project](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_management/file_management.html#projects) is a set of JSON-formatted files that keeps track of files and folders that are open in Sublime at any one time. In your case, `My First Project.sublime-project` probably contains the directory `C:\MAMP\htdocs`. The other file, `My First Project.sublime-workspace`, contains very detailed information about what files are open and what is currently visible in the window, what's selected, previously-opened files, and other data. When you created and saved `index.html` and `main.css`, they were saved on your hard drive in `C:\MAMP\htdocs`, along with the project files.

You then closed your first project, and created a second one. You edited and saved `new_project.html` and saved it in `C:\MAMP\htdocs`. This folder now contains **all** of the files - both HTML files, the CSS file, and all of the project files, along with the other files and folders in your image.

I think you might be confusing Sublime projects with git (or other version control system) branches. A project just contains info about the files and folders contained within the project, and associated metadata. It can exist alongside other files and folders (and even other projects) just fine, and **all** of the files will be visible in the containing folder. In a git repo, on the other hand, you can have different branches with completely different contents, with the only visible files being those contained in the active branch. If you check out a different branch, the visible files change.

Hopefully this resolves your question, if not please let me know.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I think I really do not understand htdocs very well. So Sublime Text is not a git repo where you can switch between branches with completely different contents...does this mean that if I do want to switch between different branches, I have to save the projects, htmls, css, etc on an entirely different folder and then change my root directory in MAMP to that new folder to see the changes in localhost?

Comment: @Book no need to change your root folder. Just create subfolders in `htdocs` called `project1`, `project2`, `javascript_test`, whatever you want. Put all your files in those folders, including your Sublime project files, then go to `http://localhost/project1`, etc., to see the contents.

Comment: Thank you for your insight. I didn't know that the http://localhost/new_project URL was available for use : )

Comment: @Book you can make any URL on localhost you want, including `http://localhost/this_is_a_very_long_url_to_type_in_but_I'm_Making_you_do_it_any_way_just_for_fun`. It's **your** server.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to change the directory in your command line or terminal to the project you are working on.  For Example, in terminal you would type "cd" for change directory then space then the folder your are working with. In addition, you should run your local Apache server using XAMPP with a windows machine.